# Is it possible to force Tridion 2011 SP1 installer to overwrite files?

Tags: installation, tridion, tridion-2011

After having applied the SP1 on a Tridion 2011 installation, we are facing some issues with the Content Manager GUI: The internet browser is displaying a blank page with JS errors.

Ex:

```
[16:19:41,144] $dom is undefined @ http://localhost/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard_v6.1.0.55920.5_.aspx?mode=js:15
```

In the windows explorer, we can see that the file %TRIDION_HOME%\web\webUI\Core\Client\Base\Utils\Css.js has not been updated by the installer (modified date).

In the installer logs, we have found the followings lines:

```
MSI (s) (C0:2C) [17:59:54:643]: File: F:\Tridion\web\WebUI\Core\Client\Base\Utils\Css.js;   Won't Overwrite;    Won't patch;    Existing file is unversioned but modified
```

After having checked the patches previously installed on this server, I've found one which is containing a version of css.js : CM_2011.0.1.76243. I suppose this is the reason why the installer doesn't update this file.

Does this mean that we can't upgrade a Tridion 2011 env that have been previously patched ? Do we need to first uninstall Tridion 2011 or is there a way to force the installer to overwrite existing files ?

Answer (score 5):

The support has confirmed the defect:

> There is indeed a defect where the installer should copy files to a
>   file system that have been modified, updated or replaced. For now (as
>   you noticed), the only way to notify this is to look in the installer
>   log and search for "Won't Overwrite; Won't patch; Existing file is
>   un-versioned but modified" messages.
>
> There should be no requirement for uninstalling SDL Tridion 2011 GA
>   first, but rather looking at the installer log and then requesting us
>   the problematic files.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is such an option available indeed, one of the things I found in the upgrade manual was:

> **Uninstalling add-on products**
>
> If you have any add-on products installed, even if they are compatible with SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, uninstall all of them. Compatible add-ons minimally require an uninstall and reinstall.

Guess that also applies to patches which are not versioned. So if the installer log only mentioned that file, I would just delete it and run a repair, see if you get the correct file back. Or if possible remove it before you perform the upgrade. If the installer log mentions more files, do the same with those.

*One thing to note, if that file is coming from a official hotfix, I would report this issue to SDL Tridion Customer Support (you might even consider reporting it if you have manually changed the file). Could be a defect in the upgrade installer that it doesn't correctly identify this (officially changed) file. Certainly something which could be improved then.*